# Sort UNC list of files by particular Folder

Tags: sorting, powershell

I have a bunch of servers with a common set of log folders. Given UNC root paths, I have a script to find the log files I require.
However I cannot seem to figure out how to sort them based on the 'Service' which is a folder down the path, for example my script returns the below

```
\\Server1\C$\Logs\ServiceA\Logs\File.log
\\Server1\C$\Logs\ServiceC\Logs\File.log
\\Server2\C$\Logs\ServiceB\Logs\File.log
\\Server2\C$\Logs\ServiceD\Logs\File.log
```

How could I sort these results alphabetically by the 'Service' folder?

I can seem to figure out a split, sort, join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the criteria for [`Sort-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx) as a scriptblock where you strip the input of everything that you don't want considered, e.g. like this:

```
... | Sort-Object { $_ -replace '.*\\(Service[^\\]*)\\.*', '$1' }
```

or like this (if all UNC paths have the same structure):

```
... | Sort-Object { ([uri]$_).Segments[3] }
```

Comment: Wonderful, I used the "{ ([uri]$_).Segments[3] }" and it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: Paste `[uri]'\\Server1\C$\Logs\ServiceA\Logs\File.log'` in a PowerShell console and take a look at the output.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation too. I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Uris = '\\Server2\C$\Logs\ServiceD\Logs\File.log',
'\\Server1\C$\Logs\ServiceC\Logs\File.log',
'\\Server1\C$\Logs\ServiceA\Logs\File.log',
'\\Server2\C$\Logs\ServiceB\Logs\File.log'
$Uris | sort {([uri]$_).segments[3]}
```